# Is it possible to write custom code at Azure APIM

Tags: angular, azure, azure-api-management, azure-ad-msal

I am using Angular SPA and Azure AD for Authentication. My requirement is, if the user is not authenticated, he should be redirected directly to MS Login page without downloading SPA at browser. (Since AuthGaurd will also work only after downloading SPA and SPA page will be visible for some moment.

I am thinking to redirect SPA at APIM first and at APIM i check if user is Authenticated or not. If user is not Authenticated, i will redirect ir to MS Login page.

1- Can i write such login in APIM ?
2- Will this approach affact silent authentication for Token refresh ( I am using MSAL at Client) ?
3- What can be other best approach redirect to MS Login page without downloading SPA on first request ?

I have just analyzed and tried to find out the best approach but could found a concrete solution to redirect to MS Login page without downloading SPA.

Comment: I'm not sure whether API Management is the right tool for the job. You basically want to achieve a redirect on a certain URL when a session is not authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

While Azure API Management is primarily designed for APIs, it still possible to host your SPA behind it. There are 2 keys things to look at for

1. Use a GET operation like this

   > [image: apim-get-operation-spa]
2. Use the [`redirect-content-urls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#MaskURLSContent) policy in the outbound block of your policy

   > [image: apim-operation-policy-spa]

Coming to your other queries

1. Yes. You can use the [`validate-jwt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT) in your `inbound` scope and in the [`on-error` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-error-handling-policies), redirect the user to the login page.

   Also, since you don't have any JavaScript loaded at this point, you will have to use a `redirect_uri` which comes back to APIM and sets the returned access token in the header and then `validate-jwt`.

   Since the validation would succeed, it would now load the `index.html` and in the response, you would want to have a `Set-Cookie` header to return the access token to the browser and would automatically be sent in the follow up requests for other resources (and API calls).
2. Kind of. APIM would be returning a token first to get the SPA files (which can be used for the API calls as well) **but** with the MSAL client, your SPA would be fetching a token too resulting in 2 tokens.

   Ideally, sensitive data in cookies should be protected by using Secure and Http Only cookies. You can read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies).
   With such cookies, your JS can't access the token, but the cookie will be sent in all requests to the same domain, which APIM can extract.
   So, you could remove the MSAL code from your app.
3. The above is a reasonably good way of achieving what you require.